What do I need for a strong (undergraduate) background in number theory and combinatorics?
Context: I'm an undergraduate and I've taken courses in elementary number theory, undergraduate analysis, algebra, and measure theory. The two subjects which interest me the most are number theory and combinatorics, and I'd like to do research someday in those areas. To prepare, I'm planning on taking courses in complex analysis, analytic number theory, algebraic number theory, and enumerative combinatorics.
I unfortunately don't have much time left in college, so I want to make sure I get the most solid background I can, without missing anything critical or interesting.
Questions: Are there any important topics I shouldn't miss? For instance, I've heard that algebraic geometry is sometimes utilized in number theory. Would doing introductory classes in ANT and AG be more beneficial to my understanding (or context) than say, a two course sequence in ANT? I'm also going to take a standard undergraduate course in complex analysis; is it worthwhile to do a second course afterwards, solely for the purpose of number theory?
For combinatorics, I'm more certain on what I'm going to do--after my first course, perhaps some graph theory or algebraic combinatorics. But I'd be grateful for any input or suggestions.

Do you mean "analysis, algebra, and..." or did you take a course called "analysis/algebra?" Abstract algebra would definitely be something you need for algebraic geometry, but your notation doesn't make it clear if you've covered any of that.

Sorry for the ambiguity; I edited it. I took analysis and algebra separately. I've done group theory, and will be covering rings, fields, and Galois theory, either in my own time or in a course.

There is a good possibility that this question gets closed as off-topic (it's at 2 close votes), so just in case, I'll suggest that r/math on Reddit might be a good forum to post this question to.

If you're interested in algebraic geometry, here is a page with Ravi Vakil's advice for prospective students: https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/potentialstudents.html The advice is for graduate students, but there is some generally good advice on there, and you can also view it as a long-term goal

For ANT and AG you want commutative algebra. This goes beyond a pure "algebra" course
